# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) for Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, ssms-2016

I am using Windows 7 64 Bit and "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.0.6556" for Windows Server 2008.

Now we are using "Microsoft SQL Server 2019" and I need an update for SSMS.
But the new versions of SSMS no longer support Windows 7, at least with version 18.8 that is no longer in the list of supported Windows versions.

What is the latest SSMS version that is still running for Windows 7?

Comment: The real solution is update your version of Windows; Windows 7 has been completely unsupported for over a year now.

Comment: Also, no version of SSMS 18 supports Windows 7, and SSMS 18+ is required for support of SQL Server 2019. If you want to use SSMS to connect to SQL Server 2019 in a supported manner you **must** use Windows 8.1/Windows Server 2008 R2 (which is also completely unsupported) or later.

Comment: Finally, SSMS 17 *was* supported on Windows 7, however, (as I mention) does not support SQL Server 2019 so it will not recognise the latest features in the version, and could result in unexpected behaviour when using some features. it is not advised to be used for a version of SQL Server it does not support.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations. In the worst case, what can happen if I access SQL Server 2019 with my old SSMS? I use mostly simple select, update, and insert commands. And I create new tables. But I don't do more with it.

Comment: There is no guaranteed behaviour (good or bad) when using incompatible clients. If this is on a business system, it is likely a breach of your IT acceptable use policy.